# Which view controller should be the initial view controller if I have a tutorial that shows on first launch?

Tags: ios

On first launch users are welcomed by a tutorial. Should this be the initial view controller or the view controller that comes after completing the tutorial, which should be first for users who return to the app after completing the tutorial.

Comment: My mistake, just did. Thank you for the explanation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should have the controller that comes **after** the tutorial controller as initial. What you should do in that controller is to make a check, if the user should see the tutorial then you should segue to that controller otherwise don´t do anything. You can store the value (if the user should see the tutorial) in a `UserDefault`.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response just fixed it!

Comment: @dfd "Stack Overflow is the largest, most trusted online community for developers to learn, share their knowledge, and build their careers." Key phrase "share their knowledge". Was this question as beneficial for others as many other questions on this forum? Arguably not. Was I able to make progress in my project? Absolutely! Hope that answers your question. Once again, thank you Rashwan L. You were a big help!